# React - Force horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, reactjs

Is there a way in React I can force scrolling down to move horizontally instead of up/down?

I'm unsure how to approach in the handleScroll() method:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

method:

```
  scroll(e) {
    window.scrollBy(e.deltaY, 0)
  }
```

usage:

```
<Component onWheel={this.scroll} />
```